# includegraphics in tikz node disappears when compat=1.3 changes to compat=newest

Tags: tikz-pgf, includegraphics

I have a `tikzpicture` where I draw a plot and add two png files on top of the plot. I add the png files with

```
\node at (400,90) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{figures/time_series/texas.png}};
```

When the `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}` it works exactly as I like, but now that I try to clean/refactor my code into what is most up-to-date, I realize it does not work. Meaning that when I do `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}`, I **do not** get an error, but the two png images disappear. I only see the plot itself.

Does anyone have an idea why `\includegraphics` stop functioning?

Note: I use TeXLive 2022, so I have version 3.1.9a as the pgf `newest` version.

Comment: You probably added that node inside an `axis`. WIth `compat=1.11` or newer the coordinates of `\node`, `\draw` etc. are seen as axis coordinates. So with `compat=1.3` and `compat=newest` your `(400, 90)` coordinate is interpreted differently.

Comment: Yes, that was precisely it. Thanks a lot!